# extending http.IncomingMessage and http.ServerResponse & providing it to the http.createServer . How to do that in TS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, nodejs-server

I want to provide my own custom `http.IncomingMessage` and `http.ServerResponse` class to `http.createServer(opt,fn)` .
I have been searching for about 2 hour to find a way to this in typescript . But it didn't help . But this same code works in JS . Please help me .
I just want to provide a custom Request and Response Object to the http.createServer() .

Here is my **server.js** JAVASCRIPT file .

```js
const { createServer, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } = require("http");

class Request extends IncomingMessage {
  constructor(socket) {
    super(socket);
  }

  getMeAnything() {
    return "you got REQUEST";
  }
}

class Response extends ServerResponse {
  constructor(req) {
    super(req);
  }

  getMeAnything() {
    return "you got  RESPONSE";
  }
}

const server = createServer(
  {
    IncomingMessage: Request,
    ServerResponse: Response,
  },
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.getMeAnything());

    res.end("Hello How are you ?");
  }
);

server.listen(3000);
```

here is my **server.ts** TYPESRIPT file :

```js
import { Socket } from "net";
import { createServer, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from "http";

class Req extends IncomingMessage {
  constructor(socket: Socket) {
    super(socket);
  }

  getMeAnything() {
    return "you got anything inside REQUEST";
  }
}

class Res extends ServerResponse {
  constructor(req: IncomingMessage) {
    super(req);
  }

  getMeAnything() {
    return "you got anything inside RESPONSE";
  }
}

const server = createServer(
  {
    IncomingMessage: Req,
    ServerResponse: Res,
  },
  (req: Req, res: Res) => {
  
    // here I get a big fat error . Some suggested me to write @ts-ignore . But I think there is a solution for it . 
    
    console.log(req.getMeAnything());

    res.end("Hello How are you ?");
  }
);

server.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript extension of ServerResponse should be defined like bellow:

```js
import {IncomingMessage, ServerResponse} from "http";

export class Response<Request extends IncomingMessage = IncomingMessage> extends ServerResponse<Request> {
  redirect(url) {
    this.writeHead(301, {Location: url}).end();
  }
}
```